# Issue while Passing configured values to JMeter Time function

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Below statement generates date with 20 days added with out any issues.
String schedule = "${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd,,P20D,,)}" +"T00:00:00.000Z";

I have configured number 20 in JMeter user defined variables
ADD_DAYS_COUNT =20 and accessing/using this variable in

Beanshell pre-processor.
String schedule_end = "${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd,,P${ADD_DAYS_COUNT}D,,)}" +"T00:00:00.000Z";

It returns "Text cannot be parsed in timeshift function. How can I convert to int and pass it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is correct,

I have sample for you to double check,

- config one variable named: `ADD_DAYS_COUNT=20`
- add *BeanShell PreProcessor* & script

  `String schedule_start = "${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd,,}D,,)}" +"T00:00:00.000Z";`
  `String schedule_end = "${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd,,P${ADD_DAYS_COUNT}D,,)}" +"T00:00:00.000Z";`

  `vars.put("schedule_start", schedule_start);`
  `vars.put("schedule_end", schedule_end);`
- add **JSR223 Sampler** to print result to console

here is the result.

*schedule_start: 2023-07-24T00:00:00.000Z*

*schedule_end: 2023-08-13T00:00:00.000Z*

[image]